# How to output only the string input of the JSON that's returned?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am struggling to get just the data that is input to display into the span for my AJAX request, it's showing the full object by the looks of it. How do I adjust this so it outputs only the string that is input?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Random Input</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Data Lookup</legend>
        <label for="data"></label>
        <input type="data" name="firstData" id="firstData" placeholder= "Input">
        <input type="submit" id="inputSubmit">
      </fieldset>
    </form>

  <h2>Output</h2>
<ul>
    <li>
  <span>Data Output: </span><span id="newData"></span></li>
 </ul>
<script src="input.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bindButtons);

function bindButtons(){
  document.getElementById('inputSubmit').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var payload = {firstData:null};
    payload.firstData = document.getElementById('firstData').value;
    req.open('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.addEventListener('load',function(){
      if(req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400){
        var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        document.getElementById('firstData').textContent = response.firstData;
        document.getElementById('newData').innerHTML = response.data;
      } else {
        console.log("Error in network request: " + req.statusText);
      }});
    req.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

Comment: try to change type to text

Comment: Hmmm that didn't fix it but that was an error. I think it may have to do with this line            document.getElementById('newData').innerHTML = response.data;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following:
`document.getElementById('newData').innerHTML = response.data;` with
`document.getElementById('newData').innerHTML = JSON.parse(response.data).firstData;`.

Hope this will help!